# Linking to child router outlet

Tags: angular

I have the following routes defined in a child route module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ''  ,
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'application',
    component: ApplicationComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ApplicationStep1Component,
        outlet: "appSteps"
      },
      {
        path: 'step1',
        component: ApplicationStep1Component,
        outlet: "appSteps"
      },
      {
        path: 'step2',
        component: ApplicationStep2Component,
        outlet: "appSteps"
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ApplicationsRoutingModule { }
```

where the parent routes look like this

```
const  routes = [
     {
       path: 'applications',
       loadChildren: './applications/applications.module#ApplicationsModule'
     }
  ];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: []
})
```

In my dashboard component, I have a navigation bar where I would like to link to a component inside a nested `router-outlet`, so "Step 1" and "Step" would show inside the `router-outlet` when the links are clicked.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['step1']">Step 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['step2']">Step 1</a>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- end .row -->

  <router-outlet name="appSteps"></router-outlet>
```

When the `applications/application` route is activated, the Step1 component is displayed correctly, but if I try to use the nav bar, I end up with errors in the console telling me `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'applications/application/step1'`.

I have tried variations of the path to `step1`, but still end up with the same error.

I'm sure that what I am trying to do is possible, but I'm obviously not searching for the right terms...   What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow this syntax for activating secondary router-outlet

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="[{ outlets:{ appSteps: ['step1']} }]">Step 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="[{ outlets:{ appSteps: ['step2']} }]">Step 1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This works (and thank you so much!), but do you have any idea why they didn't have to follow this syntax in the Angular demos here ?https://stackblitz.com/angular/kopkkdabvxmv

Comment: App.component.html in this page they have followed same syntax only